# Retrieving MS Access Database to vb6 and filter data using 2 DTpicker for the sum rate

Tags: sql, vb6

[image]

```
   Private Sub Command5_Click()
   Dim li As ListItem
   Dim lngRunningTotal As Long

   For Each li In ListView1.ListItems
      lngRunningTotal = lngRunningTotal + CLng(li.SubItems(6)) 'calculate all the in Total min column
   Next

   sumText.Text = CStr(lngRunningTotal) 'display total
End Sub
```

I want to filter data using 2 DTpicker for the sum rate.

Comment: What is `sum rate`?  Are there dates in the ListView?  If so, which SubItems?  We need more information to help you.  Please edit your question and add more detail.

Comment: I want to search the date in listview using dtpicker and calculate the number of Total Min column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with the code you posted:

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
    Dim li As ListItem
    Dim lngRunningTotal As Long
    Dim iLogDateIndex As Integer
    Dim iMinutesIndex As Integer

    iLogDateIndex = 5
    iMinutesIndex = 6

    For Each li In ListView1.ListItems

        If CDate(li.SubItems(iLogDateIndex)) >= DTPickerStart And CDate(li.SubItems(iLogDateIndex)) <= DTPickerEnd Then
            lngRunningTotal = lngRunningTotal + CInt(li.SubItems(iMinutesIndex)) ' calculate all the in Total min column
        End If

    Next

    ' Display total
    sumText.Text = CStr(lngRunningTotal)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir , I already tried that code but mine is not working i guess I put wrong index , Thank you sir .

Answer (score 1):

The following demonstrates how to filter your data using an SQL Statement:

```
Private Sub cmdQuery_Click()
    Dim objAdoConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnectionString As String
    Dim sSQLStatement As String
    Dim sDatabaseFile As String
    Dim itm As ListItem

    ' Path to Access database
    sDatabaseFile = "C:\Temp\Stack\ADO\Database.accdb"

    ' Connection string
    sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & sDatabaseFile

    ' Open Connection
    objAdoConnection.Open sConnectionString

    ' Open recordset with SQL query
    sSQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM TimeCards WHERE WorkDate BETWEEN #" & DTPickerStart & "# AND #" & DTPickerEnd & "#"
    Set objRecordset = objAdoConnection.Execute(sSQLStatement)

    ' Clear ListView
    ListView1.ListItems.Clear

    ' Move Recordset to first record
    objRecordset.MoveFirst

    ' Display record data
    Do While Not objRecordset.EOF

        ' Add record to ListView
        Set itm = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , objRecordset.Fields("ID"))
        itm.SubItems(1) = objRecordset.Fields("EmployeeID")
        itm.SubItems(2) = objRecordset.Fields("WorkDate")
        itm.SubItems(3) = objRecordset.Fields("WorkHours")

        ' Move to next record
        objRecordset.MoveNext

    Loop

    ' Close connection and release objects
    objAdoConnection.Close
    Set objRecordset = Nothing
    Set objAdoConnection = Nothing

End Sub
```

I made a quick UI with two DTPicker controls and a Query button. The results get shown into a ListView control:

[image: Database Query UI]

I also created a simple TimeCards table with the following data for testing:

[image: TimeCards Table]

You can research SQL Statements on the internet and find many ways you can filter your data.

Comment: The wheels come off if you have user locales where the date formatting is inconsistent with Jet SQL's format for date-time literals.  Use a parameter query and pass it Date typed data instead of cobbling together String queries this way.

Comment: Indeed, the wheels do come off pretty easily when manually building SQL statements, my apologies for setting a bad example!